# Proving Euclid's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

The lemma is shown in several ways. This is what I am exposed to (the simplest case I assume):

Let $p, a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p > 1$. Then p is a prime $\iff p|ab \implies p|a \lor p|b$

I want to show two directions:

"$\implies$" is something that I am alright with.

"$\impliedby$" is what I am having difficulty with.

As a start, suppose for a contradiction that $p$ is not prime. Then $\exists$ $s,t$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$.

I'm not sure as to where to continue on from there to achieve a contradiction.

Comment: just find $a$,$b$, such that $p|ab$ but neither $p|a$ nor $p|b$. (hint: $p|p$)

Comment: Right. So I consider $p = st$, where $s,t \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$. Then I take $p|p$. But $p$ cannot be a factor of $s$ and $p$ cannot be a factor of $t$. Since $p=st$ and neither $s$ or $t$ is 1, we get that $s<p$ and $t<p$. This means that our initial assumption of $p = st$ is false and therefore p must be prime?

Comment: Right!  contradiction to condition disproves the initial assumption.

Comment: First, $A\iff B\implies C$ is ambiguous without brackets. Second, it doesn't make sense (at least, doesn't say what you want it to say) with "Let $p,a,b\in\mathbb N$" all at the beginning. Here's how you write it correctly:  Let $p\in\mathbb N$ with $p\gt1.$ Then $p$ is a prime $\iff$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb N(p|ab\iff[p|a\vee p|b]).$

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the standard proof of Euclid's Lemma:

Let $p$ be a prime number that divides $ab$ but does not divide $a$. We must show that $p$ divides $b$. Since $p$ does not divide $a$, there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $1=am+pn$. Then $b=abm+pnb$, and since $p$ divides the right-hand side of this equation, $p$ also divides $b$.

Comment: @agra94 By multiplying both sides by $b$.